Abigen unable to generate go code for solidity enum type used inside a library used by other contracts
I am receiving the following error from abigen:
$ abigen --abi abi.json --pkg versioning --type Versioning --out versioning.go
Fatal: Failed to generate ABI binding: unsupported arg type: State

For simplicity I have produced a minimal reproducible copy of what is causing the error, from my actual code, with an example code shown below.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

enum State {
    UNINITIALISED,
    INIT,
    OPEN
}

library Versioning {
    function versionState(
        State state,
        string calldata version
    ) external pure returns (string memory versionedState) {
        if (state == State.OPEN) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "OPEN"));
        }
        if (state == State.INIT) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "INIT"));
        }
        if (state == State.UNINITIALISED) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "UNINITIALISED"));
        }
        return "UNKNOWN STATE";
    }
}

When running the following set of commands:
$ forge build mrc.sol
$ jq .abi ./out/mrc.sol/Versioning.json > abi.json
$ abigen --abi abi.json --pkg versioning --type Versioning --out versioning.go
Fatal: Failed to generate ABI binding: unsupported arg type: State

I am able to reproduce the code generation error. Any help and guidance is appreciated If possible I would like to keep code change to a minimal as this is part of a much larger project and the typescript bindings generated with the same contract files are able to use the same code. For this example using typechain, from ./out/mrc.sol/Versioning.json generates a Versioning.ts file that correctly identifies this enum and converts it to a BigNumberish, using the following command:
$ typechain --target ethers-v6 --out-dir . ./out/mrc.sol/Versioning.json

...
  versionState: TypedContractMethod<
    [state: BigNumberish, version: string],
    [string],
    "view"
  >;
...

I would expect the enum in question to be converted to some integer type in Go, math/big's big.Int or an int{,8,32,64}/uint{,8,32,64} but due to the abigen failure not a single piece of Go code is generated for this one file. I have another enum, defined outside of the library right next to the one called State here that is converted to uint8 in the Go code generated by a separate contract that imports the type from the library as defined above. For example:
// mrc.sol

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

enum Example {
    THIS,
    IS,
    AN,
    EXAMPLE,
    ENUM
}

enum State {
    UNINITIALISED,
    INIT,
    OPEN
}

library Versioning {
    function versionState(
        State state,
        string calldata version
    ) external pure returns (string memory versionedState) {
        if (state == State.OPEN) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "OPEN"));
        }
        if (state == State.INIT) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "INIT"));
        }
        if (state == State.UNINITIALISED) {
            return string(abi.encodePacked(version, "UNINITIALISED"));
        }
        return "UNKNOWN STATE";
    }
}

// import.sol

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

import { Example } from "./mrc.sol";

contract ExampleContract {
    constructor() {}

    function exampleType(
        Example exm
    ) external pure returns (string memory example) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked("example", exm));
    }
}

Using the commands below generates the following Go code:
$ forge buid mrc.sol import.sol
$ jq .abi ./out/import.sol/ExampleContract.json > abi.json
$ abigen --abi abi.json --pkg example --type Example --out example.go
# No errors

...
// ExampleType is a free data retrieval call binding the contract method 0xd19b25d7.
//
// Solidity: function exampleType(uint8 exm) pure returns(string example)
func (_Example *ExampleCaller) ExampleType(opts *bind.CallOpts, exm uint8) (string, error) {
    var out []interface{}
    err := _Example.contract.Call(opts, &out, "exampleType", exm)

    if err != nil {
        return *new(string), err
    }

    out0 := *abi.ConvertType(out[0], new(string)).(*string)

    return out0, err

}
...

Any and all help is appreciated, please take into account that this library is used in numerous places of our solidity codebase so if possible minimal changes to it would be ideal. Other enums are defined alongside the one described here and work. Should this library just not try to have its code generated (am I just trying to do something I shouldn't) or is there something else I ought to do as I don't understand why typechain can figure it out but abigen cannot, so simply ignoring it from the go binding generation logic doesn't make sense either.
Many thanks.
